# Os ângulos estão loucos!

Tags: winforms, vb.net, matemática

Estou criando um simples sistema de órbita, onde têm a terra e o sol, criados com base num `UserControl`, o problema é que eu não sei porque o ângulo fica *maluco* ao colocar um ângulo na propriedade `Angle`. O controle é isso:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E aqui está seu código:

```
Public Property Angle As Integer
Private Sub Orbit_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles Me.Paint
    Dim g_ As Graphics = e.Graphics
    g_.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality
    Dim p As New Pen(Color.White, 1)
    Dim myRect = Me.ClientRectangle
    Dim origin As New Point(myRect.Width / 2, myRect.Height / 2)
    g_.DrawEllipse(p, myRect)

    Dim r = myRect.Height / 2
    Dim a = Angle

    Dim nx = r * Cos(a) + origin.X
    Dim ny = r * Sin(a) + origin.Y

    Dim np As New Point(nx, ny)

    Dim ax_earth As New Point(np.X - 5, np.Y - 5)
    Dim ax_sun As New Point(origin.X - 5, origin.Y - 5)

    g_.DrawLine(New Pen(Color.Gray, 1), origin, np)
    g_.FillEllipse(New SolidBrush(Color.DeepSkyBlue), New Rectangle(ax_earth, New Size(5, 5)))
    g_.FillEllipse(New SolidBrush(Color.Gold), New Rectangle(ax_sun, New Size(10, 10)))

End Sub
```

Usei [coordenadas polares](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordenadas_polares) para calcular o ponto **x, y** de onde irá ficar o planeta terra, as fórmulas são as seguintes:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O **r** é o tamanho horizontal divido por dois. O **θ** é definido pela propriedade `Angle`

### O problema

Até ai beleza, quando por exemplo coloco na propriedade `Angle` 90, o correto era ficar no meio horizontal perfeito, mas foi isso o que deu:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Então, testei com **120**:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Creio que o problema está na linha `Dim a = Angle`, mas sinceramente não sei a fórmula para resolver isso. Como deixo o ângulo perfeito, mais ou menos assim[?]:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bom, fuçando um pouco e lendo um pouco sobre trigonometria eu apênas dividi o ângulo por 180 e multipliquei pelo PI, assim:

```
Dim a = Angle / 180 * PI
```

e deu certo. Sinceramente não sabia como resolver isso, e magicamente uma luz do céu veio e resolveu meu problema espontaneamente.

Comment: Isso é porque *Angle* tem que ser informado em Radianos, não em Graus...

Comment: Não sou bom em matemática... :P

Comment: https://pt.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radiano

Comment: Agora que vc já sabe que tem que ser em radianos, tenta usar uma elipse ao invés de um círculo. Fica mais bacana, por parecer mais próximo da órbita real. :) Usa as coordenadas polares da elipse, mas com raios diferentes na vertical e na horizontal (a e b ao invés de r). https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elipse#Coordenadas_polares